# WebView working (slowly) but not at all with Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

I'm trying to use a WebView to display a Google Maps webpage. If I use a target URL of something like 'http://www.google.co.uk' or 'http://www.youtube.com' the webview works, but not when I use 'http://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir//NEC,+North+Avenue,+Birmingham/'

The WebView does not work with the Maps URL and displays an empty white box

Java Class:

```
public class location_Fragment extends Fragment {

private WebView webView;

View rootview;

@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_layout, container, false);
    webView = (WebView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir//NEC,+North+Avenue,+Birmingham/");
    return rootview;
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package= ... >

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

 <application ...
 </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: are you getting any error? is so please post here.

Comment: No errors, just a blank white box (empty WebView)